# Ruby on Rails 3 - to_json not including all attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using the `to_json` method on my model object that I created by doing something like:

`user = User.find(1)`

When I do `user.to_json`, a lot of attributes are missing, including `user.id` from the encoded JSON string. It appears that all of the attributes that I've added as attr_accessible from the User model are there, but none of the others. Perhaps that is what to_json is doing, but I think that adding `id` to attr_accessible is a no go.

What is the right way of solving this problem?

**UPDATE**

This looks to be a specific issue with Devise. If I comment out the following from user.rb, everything works as expected:

`devise :rememberable, :trackable, :token_authenticatable, :omniauthable`

Comment: This is really weird... what if you type explicitly `user.to_json(:except => :created_at)`.

Comment: did you try to work from console? what about the object before to_json? does it have all the attributes set?

Comment: the object _does_ contain id before the to_json (verified in console). I tried (:except => :created_at) and that didn't do it. I wonder if Devise is doing something odd to my object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't checked but I believe Devise does that for you; it includes only certain attributes via attr_accessible.

In any case the right way to solve this is to override the `as_json` method like so:

```
def as_json(options = nil)
  {
    my_attr: my_attr,
    etc: etc
  }
end
```

It's a simple hash and it's a really powerful method to generate JSON in AR, without messing with the `to_json` method.

Answer (score 3):

Devise indeed filters the attributes for you, as mentioned by kain.
Nevertheless, I'd rather just append exactly what I need to instead of overriding Devise's logic.

Instead, I'd rather do

```
def as_json(options={})
  json_res = super options
  json_res['locked_at'] = self.locked_at
  json_res['confirmed_at'] = self.confirmed_at
end
```

or whatever other attributes your user might have that you want to pass

Answer (score 2):

By default Devise overrides the serializable_hash method to expose only accessible attributes (so things like the encrypted_password doesn't get serialized by default on APIs).

You could try to override this method and add the auth_token to the hash, something like this:

def serializable_hash(options = nil)
  super(options).merge("auth_token" => auth_token)
end

Answer (score 2):

If you came here looking for Rails 4, like I did, here's some information that will help.

As Alan David Garcia said above, Devise overrides `serializable_hash`.  To force an override, you could do the following, for example, to return all attributes except `password_digest` when calling `Model#as_json`.

```
def as_json(options = {})
  options[:force_except] ||= [:password_digest]
  super(options)
end
```

You can specify any desired model attributes to exclude in `options[:force_except]` instead of just `:password_digest`.

Answer (score 0):

include something like this in your model class:

```
  attr_accessible :id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

Initially the id wasn't included in json but after I added it to attr_accessible it worked!!